# meteor and semantic UI, modal get value

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I would like to put a form in a modal using Semantic UI. I can't find the way to get the values of the form in the template events ...
Could you help me please?

Here is the JS:

```
Template.riderForm.events({
'click .newRiderButton': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
},
'click #new-rider-submit': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var firstname   = event.target.firstname.value;
    var lastname    = event.target.lastname.value;

    Riders.insert({
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        createdAt: new Date()
    });

    event.target.firstname.value    = "";
    event.target.lastname.value     = "";

    $('.ui.modal').modal('hide');
}
});
```

And the Html:

```
<template name="riderForm">
<button 
    class="ui button icon right labeled teal newRiderButton" 
    type="newRiderButton" 
    name="newRiderButton">
    <i class="right checkmark icon"></i>New rider
</button>


<div class="ui large modal">
<i class="close icon"></i>
<div class="header">Add someone</div>
<form class="ui form new-rider content">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="two fields">
                <div class="four wide field">
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name">
                </div>
                <div class="four wide field">
                    <label>last name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="actions">
<div id="new-rider-submit"  class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
    <i class="right checkmark icon"></i>Send
</div>
 </div>
</form>
</div>

</template>
```

I don't understand because it doesn't even go to the event function ... (tried with a console.log ...

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idk why the event isn't firing, but you can use Approve / Deny Callbacks

```
Template.riderForm.events({
'click .newRiderButton': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.ui.modal')
    .modal({
      onApprove : function() {
        console.log('click #new-rider-submit');

        var firstname   = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
        var lastname    = $('input[name="lastname"]').val();

        Riders.insert({
          firstname: firstname,
          lastname: lastname,
          createdAt: new Date()
        });

        $('input[name="firstname"]').val("");
        $('input[name="firstname"]').val("");

        $('.ui.modal').modal('hide');
      }
    })
    .modal('show');
}
});
```

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#approve--deny-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Can't quite tell why your event isn't firing, it should be.

However your logic for getting the field values:

```
var firstname   = event.target.firstname.value;
var lastname    = event.target.lastname.value;
```

is incorrect because `event.target` will be the `#new-rider-submit` div, not the `.ui.large.modal` div. You can easily get the field values by name instead:

```
var firstname   = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
var lastname    = $('input[name="lastname"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't find the reason, but events of template element that defined inside a modal, didn't fire in meteor. but if you separate modal content to another templates and attach events to them. and only render them inside the modal, they are perfect!!!!

***this didn't work***

**HTML**

```
<template name="firstModal">
    <div id="firstModal" class="ui wide modal">
        <i class="close icon"></i>
        <input type="button" class="ui button" value="click me">
    </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.firstModal.events({
    'click .button': function(event, template){
        alert('click !!!!!!!')
    }
});
```

***but this is perfect!!***

**HTML**

```
<template name="firstModal">
    <div id="firstModal" class="ui wide modal">
        <i class="close icon"></i>
        {{>firstModalContent}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="firstModalContent">
    <input type="button" class="ui button" value="click me">
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.firstModalContent.events({
    'click .button': function(event, template){
        alert('click !!!!!!!')
    }
});
```

[same answer...](https://github.com/nooitaf/meteor-semantic-ui/issues/25#issuecomment-190634676)

Comment: hmmm, can you include the contents of that link in the answer? :)

Comment: @khakiout ok, but... it's not so difficult to click it... ;)

Comment: thanks. the reason is that the link might be down someday or moved somewhere else. atleast future viewers can see your answers. thanks!